# Is Cookie-session the best solution for React?

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, express, session-cookies

My NodeJS application is authenticating users via third-party app. Once the app gets the user data, a cookie is being created and sent to the client and then react is reading user data from that Cookie.
Is cookie better/worse than Web tokens? AFAIK No diff but i want to be sure.
Is there a better implementation?
Can a user modifies req.session info, or that stay in the backend(Node)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Choosing between cookie and token-based approaches really **depends on your use case.** When using cookies, session id's are stored in the database. Therefore, with each request back-end will need to perform a database search to check if provided id is present. Using tokens, server only needs to process successful login requests and verify token's validity, which does not require a lot of resources and scales really well. Additionally, with tokens you may use your API outside the browser environment (cookies support is often very limited on other platforms).
If these points are not critical for your application, there is nothing wrong with using cookie-based authentication.
**Good luck!**